# Forum CMS for user?

Tags: 7, nodes

I've had a Drupal 7 site for a few months and I'm planning to create another site with a different topic. It will either be a "forum site" or a "wiki site", I have't decided yet.

For both of the options what CMS or Drupal modules would you suggest:

1. Are Drupal's forum modules sufficiently good for an advanced forum site? Or, which system do you recommend for a Drupal familiar person?
2. Is it possible to create wiki sites with Drupal? If not, which system do you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Picking your software before you select the style of the site is, in my opinion, putting the cart before the horse.

Depending on the details of your final specification Drupal is likely capable of all you'll need, but it might not be the best tool for the job. You might be happier with a MediaWiki for a wiki site, or any one of the dedicated forum systems for a purely forum site.

Develop your goals and specs first, then determine the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

Drupal has an [advanced forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module which works very nicely, right out of the box.
It gives you a nice set of default themes up front.

Drupal also has a [wiki installation profile](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_wiki) that will preconfigure your Drupal site as a wiki.